# My ripple masterkey is disabled

Tags: private-key, ripple

I have XRP secret key and regular key. but masterkey is disabled.

How do i enable masterkey again to move my funds?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend that you explain more of what you already found out about having a disabled Ripple masterkey.  Questions that show some effort and thought attract more effort and thought to get themselves answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the regular key, you can create an AccountSet transaction that unsets the disable master key flag using the regular key.

Once the flag is cleared, you can use the master key again to make whatever changes you need, such as setting a new regular key.

Comment: can u show or tell me step my step please?